# Symfony2 routing.yml for comments - how do it right?

Tags: php, regex, symfony, routes, symfony-2.3

This is the routing in my Symfony2 App (part of routing.yml):

```
app_my_responses_response:
    path: /author/response/{responseId}/comments/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Response:view, page: 1 }
    methods: [GET]
    requirements:
        responseId: \d+
```

Objective of this route – execute on next cases (

1. /author/response/8293085 { page:1 }
2. /author/response/8293085/ { page:1 }
3. /author/response/8293085/comments/ { page:1 }
4. /author/response/8293085/comments/1/ { page:1 }
5. /author/response/8293085/comments/2/ { page:2 }

I have problems with urls numbered 1 and 3...and I don't know what to do...

Comment: Perhaps, use `\d*` to allow an empty match?

Comment: Remove requirements and third route should work. But first and second routes don't match your pattern. You need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is remove requirements and create another route for 1st and 3th pattern. It works for me. Thanks @kba!